# how to activate jquery ui by using clientscript in yii main config

Tags: yii

I have the following main.php config

```
    'clientScript'=>array(
        'packages'=>array(
            'jquery'=>array(
              'baseUrl'=>'../www/js/jquery/',
              'js'=>array('jquery.min.js'),
            ),

            'jquery.ui'=>array(
              'baseUrl'=>'../www/js/jquery/',
              'js'=>array('jquery.ui.js'),
            ),              
        ),
```

Both files are located in the same directory. The jquery script get loaded well but the jquery Ui does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This

```
 public function registerAssets()   {   
                  Yii::app()->getClientScript()->registerCoreScript( 'jquery.ui' );
            }
```

Comment: This worked I was under the assumption that jquery Ui was automatically loaded, just like jquery. Since I mostly use both of them together.

Answer (score 1):

According to there site you can try followings

```
    'clientScript' => array(
    'scriptMap' => array(
        'jquery.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.js',
        'jquery.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js',
        'jquery-ui.min.js' => '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js',
    ),
),
```

you can replace your jui location if u have already it in local
but they suggest to not do that, if you are curious please go to [yii site]: http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/259/serve-jquery-and-jquery-ui-from-google-s-cdn/